# How do I calculate path between two map points in Android?

Tags: android, directions

I am working on iOS/Android map application.

To find a path between two locations in iOS, I am using `MKDirectionsRequest`.

How do I do it in Android?

I found *Directions API*, which is a Web service. So that I will have to send HTTP requests.

Isn't there any Java interface to calculate directions in Android?

Comment: What mapping tool are you using?

Comment: @zed I am using Android GoogleMap.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: @zed Thank you, it seems what I needed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set this as an answer.

You can use [Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary)

[image]

As such:

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey("YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY")
        .from(new LatLng(37.7681994, -122.444538))
            .to(new LatLng(37.7749003,-122.4034934))
            .avoid(AvoidType.FERRIES)
            .avoid(AvoidType.HIGHWAYS)
            .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
        if(direction.isOK()) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```